# Dynamically load variables which contain variables which contain values from file in php

Tags: php, file, variables

Before the code I made sure the program included(_once) all the files which contain these variables with different values.
The code:

```
$mainFile = file_get_content('file.inc');
preg_match_all('/\$[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/', $mainFile, $vars);

    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($vars[0] as $var) {
        echo '<tr><td>';
        //print_r($var);
        echo "${$var}";
        echo '</tr></td>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

In this case i have output errors -- Notice: Undefined variable: '$password'... --. 
If I change

```
echo "${$var}";
```

to

```
echo "$var";
```

its output is "$password". But I want to see the VALUE of this variable ($password) what is:
"Password".
And I have 194 variables which contains values in many files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` is included in the password name in your regular expression - so you're looking up variables named `$password` - not `password` as you'd expect.

The difference can be hard to see - normally `$password` refers to a variable named `password` - which is what you'd expect. In your example, you want the result to be `${"password"}` - but you're including the `$` from your regular expression as well, effectively trying to look up a variable named `$password` - with the dollar sign present (and not a variable named `password` as you'd expect).

You can modify your regular expression by adding a capturing sub group to skip the `$`:

```
preg_match_all('/\$([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/', $mainFile, $vars);
```

.. and then use `foreach ($vars[1] as $var)` instead.

Another option is to use `ltrim` to remove the `$` prefix:

```
$var = ltrim($var, '$');
```

.. inside your `foreach`.

Comment: I don't want to create from variables values. I mean from $password is not needed to create 'password' value.$password has its own value 'Password'. I had tried your `foreach($vars[1] as $var)` but it gives back an error message **undefined offset** and **invalid argument foreach**...
Again. I have included files which contain variables. The variables are the same, its values are different. And i want output them in columns and rows. So i found all the variables, i just need their values to output. Thank you @MatsLindh

Comment: You have to change your regular expression to capture the subgroup as well. Use `var_dump` to see the contents of `$vars` if it still doesn't match. But no, I'm not talking about variable values; You're including the `$` in the name of the variable - it's not - the name is the part without the `$`, so when you're looking it up with ´${...}` you _do not_ want to include the `$` as you're doing. Please add better examples if my understanding is still not correct, with an additional minimum verifiable example.

Comment: Okay, so I was wrong, sorry for this, still not an expert. Can you give me another example so I can understand your solution? The program you see up there is the only program. Still not working. So we have **variable-strings** and I don't know how to continue. It seems you know what I try to do. Not clear for me. 
`var_dump($var)` gives me **C:\wamp64\www\myespm\test2.php:19:string '$logintitle' (length=11)
**

Comment: Which means that you still have the `$` in front of the name - this is an issue. You can use the `ltrim` function as described in my answer to remove it, or change the regex as shown. Depending on what you're attempting to do, it might however be better to return an array from your include file with the proper configuration options, instead of trying to determine which variables are present after the fact (`$settings = require 'settings.php';` -- and in `settings.php`: `return ['logintitle' => 'Title of login', 'othersetting' => 'othervalue', ...];`

Comment: Thank you for your help I had rewrote the whole file-pile :) Have a nice day, it works!